# Gradle not connecting to Maven repo

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

I've been banging my head on the wall for about a week trying to solve this issue.

I've recently started work on an app using the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/), and I keep getting the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Failure initializing default system SSL context

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I've done some extensive Googling, wherein people have suggested removing some gradle config files from ~/.gradle, making sure my Android SDK is updated, and quite a lot about corporate proxies. Well, I deleted the configs and re-generated them, I've updated EVERYTHING in my SDK, and I am not using a proxy of any kind (at least I have not gone out of my way to set any up).

When I ping `http://repo1.maven.org`, I get:

```
ping: unknown host http://repo1.maven.org
```

However, I can type the address into the address bar on Chrome and it will show me the file(s).

It is very important for me to get this working, as it's for my Senior Capstone project at University. If anyone has any ideas, I am willing to try.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Replace this with com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+ with  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0' in your build.gradle file.

Comment: I did that, for both `platforms/android/build.gradle` and `platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle`. I no longer get the error about not being able to find the repo. I get this:

    A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
       > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
         Required by:
             :android:unspecified
          > Failure initializing default system SSL context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by replacing my openjdk installation with Oracle's jdk, and updating my Android SDK with:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --filter extra
```

Apparently the GUI wasn't showing all extra options, even though I told it to reload several times.

Comment: were you using Visual Studio? I have the same issue in VS 2015.

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure "Google Repository" from your Android SDK is installed. You will find this under Extras section.